# LINQ multiple joins with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2012

I have few large tables and I need to join them. In SQL it looks like:

```
select * from dbo.Table1 t1
join dbo.Table1 t1Parent on t1.ParentId = t1Parent.Id
join dbo.MappingT1T3 t2 on t1Parent.Id = t2.ExternalId and t2.[Type] = 1
join dbo.Table3 t3 on t2.ForeignId = t3 .Id
where t1.[Type] = 3
```

Tried to convert this query to a such LINQ:

```
from t1 in dbo.Table1
join t1Parent in dbo.Table1 on t1.ParentId equals t1Parent.Id
join t2 in dbo.MappingT1T3 on new { Id = t1Parent.Id, [Type] = (int)1 } equals new { Id = t2.ExternalId, [Type] = (int)t2.[Type] }
join t3 in dbo.Table3 on t2.ForeignId equals t3.Id
where t1.[Type] == 3;
```

But seems execution plan differs a lot. Profile says that it tries to load all tables without conditions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the constant to a seperate condition...

```
from t1 in dbo.Table1
where t1.[Type] == 3 // <--- PUT THIS ONE HIGHER
join t1Parent in dbo.Table1 on t1.ParentId equals t1Parent.Id
join t2 in dbo.MappingT1T3 on t1Parent.Id equals Id = t2.ExternalId
where (int)t2.[Type] == 1 // <--- SEPARATE CONDITION
join t3 in dbo.Table3 on t2.ForeignId equals t3.Id;
```