# Joining 2 Table on 2 Equals Column in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

please help me fix my code to join 2 tables but 2 equals.
I have 2 tables (Transaction and Chartaccount)

```
Chartaccount Table
+---------+--------+
|KodeAkun |NamaAkun|
+---------+--------+
|10000    |Asset   |
|20000    |Expense |
|30000    |Revenue |
+------------------+

Transaction Table
+---------+--------+---------+-------+
|KodeAkunD| DEBIT  |KodeAkunK|KREDIT |
+---------+--------+---------+-------+
|10000    |10000   |20000    |0      |
+------------------+---------+-------+
```

In My Model

```
Chartaccount Model
public string KodeAkun {get; set;}
public string NamaAkun {get; set;}
public decimal Saldo {get; set;}

Transaction Model
public string KodeAkunD {get; set;}
public string KodeAkunK {get; set;}
public decimal Debit {get; set;}
public decimal Kredit {get; set;}
public string Keterangan {get; set;}
```

In My controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
var transaction1 = from p in _context.Transaction join k in _context.ChartAccount on p.KodeakunD equals k.Kodeakun
                           select new Transaction {
                           KodeakunD = p.KodeakunD + k.Namaakun,
                           KodeakunK = p.KodeakunK + k.Namaakun};          
return View(transaction1);
}
```

Currently in my view

```
+-----------+--------+----------+-------+-------------------+
|KodeAkunD  | DEBIT  |KodeAkunK |KREDIT |Action             |
+-----------+--------+----------+-------+-------------------+
|10000Asset |10000   |20000Asset|0      |Edit,Details,Delete|
+-----------+--------+----------+-------+-------------------+
```

what i want

```
+-----------+--------+------------+-------+-------------------+
|KodeAkunD  | DEBIT  |KodeAkunK   |KREDIT |Action             |
+-----------+--------+------------+-------+-------------------+
|10000Asset |10000   |20000Expense|0      |Edit,Details,Delete|
+-----------+--------+------------+-------+-------------------+
```

and also, if i join in controller, my action not route correctly, if i click on my action it return 404

Comment: It seems to be working as expected

Comment: it work but not work as i expected :D

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line

```
KodeakunK = p.KodeakunK + k.Namaakun
```

p.KodeakunK= 2000, but you joined table on p.KodeakunD which is the join line of 1000 that leads to ´Asset´.

You need to join KodeakunK and KodeakunD individually with Chartaccount.
You can do two different joins as alternative or you should use linq multiple joins.

Possible duplicates of [LINQ to Entity : Multiple join conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765230/linq-to-entity-multiple-join-conditions)

[Linq multiple join conditions using extra variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839843/linq-multiple-join-conditions-using-extra-variables)

[LINQ multiple joins with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368651/linq-multiple-joins-with-multiple-conditions)

[How to do joins in LINQ on multiple fields in single join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373541/how-to-do-joins-in-linq-on-multiple-fields-in-single-join)

These can help you.